# How to separate content from images into SimplePie get_description method

Tags: php, dom, rss-reader, simplepie

How can I separate the content from the images into [SimplePie](http://simplepie.org/) get_description() method?

Here is my code:

```
$feed_url = "http://www.example.com/atom.xml";

$feed = new SimplePie();
$feed->set_feed_url($feed_url);
$feed->enable_cache(false);
$feed->set_output_encoding('utf-8');
$feed->init();
$feed->handle_content_type();

$items = $feed->get_items();

for ($i=0; $i<count($items);$i++){
    print_r($items[$i]->get_description());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try foreach.
    foreach($items as $item) {
     print_r($item->get_description());
    }